# Instantiating proper generic class by type parameter in C#

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns

I have this code to perform operations under objects of Base class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Base>() { new A(), new B() };
        var v = new Visitor();
        list.ForEach(e => e.Accept(v));
    }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract void Accept(Visitor visitor);
}

public class A : Base
{
    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}

public class B : Base
{
    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}

public class Visitor
{
    Writer writer = new Writer();
    public void Visit(A a) => writer.Write(a);
    public void Visit(B b) => writer.Write(b);
}

public class Writer
{
    public void Write(A a) => Console.WriteLine("A");
    public void Write(B b) => Console.WriteLine("B");
}
```

I want to divide `Writer` into separate classes, because there will be many other entities with complex hierarchy. It could be:

```
public interface Writer<T> where T : Base
{
    void Write(T t);
}

public class WriterA : Writer<A>
{
    public void Write(A t) => Console.WriteLine("A");
}

public class WriterB : Writer<B>
{
    public void Write(B t) => Console.WriteLine("B");
}
```

but I don't know how to instantiate proper classes by the given type parameter rather than calling them explicitly. Thanks.

Comment: When you say "instantiate proper classes" do you mean you want to instantiate `A` and `B`? - In which case `public interface Writer<T> where T : Base, new()` A `new()` constraint allows you to new up the GTP.

Comment: I mean, instantiate `WriterA` and `WriterB` somehow, or maybe having them in fields and call one or another depends on signature of Visitor method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write `WriterFactory`:

```
class WriterFactory{
    Dictionary<string, Func<object>> _creators = { 
            { "A", ()=> new WriterA() },
            { "B", ()=> new WriterB() } 
       };

    public Writer<T> Create<T>(){
         return (Writer<T>)_creators[typeof(T).Name]();
    }
```

Than you can use it in `Visitor`:

```
public class Visitor
{
    Writer writerFactory = new WriterFactory();
    public void Visit(A a) => writerFactory.Create<A>().Write(a);
    public void Visit(B b) => writerFactory.Create<B>().Write(b);
}
```